# 'include' does not self-contain styling

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to set up a universal navigation bar. I'm using `include` to import `menu.php` into `index.php`. When I do, it works fine; however, when I add something after the `menu.php` include, the menu's CSS rules carries on.

*index.php*

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel=stylesheet href="css/style.css" />
    <title>Home | Website</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php include 'menu.php'; ?>
    <p>Test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

*menu.php*

```
<head>
    <title>Menu | Website</title>
    <style>
        // menu-only styles...
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="/">Home</a>
</body>
<?php return; ?>
```

Comment: You realize you can't have two `<head>` tags, right? This is what happened after you included the `menu.php`, which will put the whole content of `menu.php` on the line that says `<?php include 'menu.php'; ?>`

Comment: Even after separating the `<head>` and everything else in `menu.php`, it still doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're essentially including an HTML page within an HTML page doing it your way.

To get your CSS to target only your menu, keep it in your style.css file, but make your div have a "menu" class.

Something like this should do what you're looking for, I believe.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel=stylesheet href="css/style.css" />
  <title>Dare Network | Home</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?php include 'menu.php'; ?>
  <p>Test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
html,body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #777777;
}

.menu {
  /* padding: top&&bottom left&&right; */
  padding:10px 0;
  background-color: #7786ff;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu a {
  /* merge transitions into one line to make both functional */
  transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out, padding-bottom .25s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #b20000;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* padding:top right bottom left */
  padding:10px 10px 5px 10px;
}

.menu a:hover {
  background-color: #cc0000;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

menu.php

```
<div class="menu">
  <a href="/">Home</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked. I learned so much about PHP from this... even though it's a small thing... thanks @Jonathan! I'll mark this as answer in 7 minutes once Stack Overflow lets me. *narrows eyes at Stack Overflow*

Comment: Great!  Inspect the generated code (in Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools) to see exactly what is going on.  I updated the CSS also to give you a couple hints there, too.  :)

Answer (score 0):

**This is not a PHP issue**

Your CSS in menu.php comes later in the DOM than your actual stylesheet and therefore is being overwritten.  Either scope your menu.php styles with some containing element or put your menu CSS code earlier in the DOM (like before style.css)

Answer (score 0):

You are almost a bit closer to what you code. A HTML page can have only one html,head,title,body tag.

Just remove these html,head,title,body tags from menu.php

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
     <link rel=stylesheet href="css/style.css" />
     <title>Dare Network | Home</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php include 'menu.php'; ?>
    <p>Test
  </body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
html,body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #777777;
}
```

menu.php

```
<style>
    body {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        background-color: #7786ff;
        text-align: center;
    }

    a {
        transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
        transition: padding-bottom .25s ease-in-out;
        background-color: #b20000;
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }

    a:hover {
        background-color: #cc0000;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

</style>

<a href="/">Home</a>

<?php return; ?>
```